# iOS 7 UIAlertView Button is not visible

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview

I'm having this trouble with UIAlertview in iOS7.

I'm using basic UIAlertview init code but cancelButtonTitle text is just not showing.

Code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Feeds Saved"
                                                message:@"Feeds are saved on My Feeds Tab."
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
[alert show];
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Any idea?

Update :

I'm still having problem with this issue. I'm able to click top portion but can't show the message. 
Code runs fine in iOS6.1 but not working in iOS7

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWKpD.png

Comment: No issue in it. Just clean and build again.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YMFZ6.png

Comment: Ctl + Shift + K isn't working. Should I try anything else? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answers.

```
[UITableView appearance].contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-36, 0, -36, 0);
```

I was trying to manually set grouped tableview's top and bottom margin as I'm updating my old app to iOS7 and UiAlertView was affected by that line of code.

Hope this helps someone else.

:)

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine.

Delete the application from the simulator/device, clean the workspace/project and run it again.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. I'm still having an issue after deleting DerivedData and Ctl + Shift + K. Am I missing anything else?